# HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403 in Java

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm writing a small program and I want to fetch an element from a website. I've followed many tutorials to learn how to write this code with jSoup. An example of what I'm trying to print is "Monday, November 19, 2018 - 3:00pm to 7:00pm". I'm running into the error

```
org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403, URL=https://my.cs.ubc.ca/course/cpsc-210
```

Here is my code:

```
public class WebPageReader {
private String url = "https://my.cs.ubc.ca/course/cpsc-210";
private Document doc;

public void readPage(){
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).
                userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
                .referrer("https://www.google.com").timeout(1000).followRedirects(true).get();
        Elements temp=doc.select("span.date-display-single");
        int i=0;
        for (Element officeHours:temp){
            i++;
            System.out.println(officeHours);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Status 403 means [your access is forbidden](https://httpstatuses.com/403).

Please make sure you have an access to https://my.cs.ubc.ca/course/cpsc-210

I have tried to access https://my.cs.ubc.ca/course/cpsc-210 from browser. It returns Error Page. I think you need to use credential to access it.